# Angular 6 and Sharepoint SPFX

Tags: angular, gulp, angular6, spfx, sharepointframework

Just wondering if anyone has any samples or links to instructions for running an angular 6 app on Sharepoint SPFX.

I have followed this example for Angular 5 but it will not work once I upgrade the angular dependencies

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OgEqWtouuU

The error I get on the SPFX workbench when I try to add the webpart is

```
    [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "a884f6f5-e74c-4932-972f-0e1431147413" (AppWebPart).
Original error: ***loadComponent() returned an empty object for component "a884f6f5-e74c-4932-972f-0e1431147413" (AppWebPart).

***INNERERROR:
***loadComponent() returned an empty object for component "a884f6f5-e74c-4932-972f-0e1431147413" (AppWebPart).
***CALLSTACK:
Error
    at SPLoaderError.SPError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:10183:24)
    at new SPLoaderError (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:4211:28)
    at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:3821:21)
    at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:3743:21)
    at https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:7952:38
```

The code can be located at this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iF1Low1VYlK0RFYXf1KILZfcEuLnMIjx/view?usp=sharing

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you 
Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work running an Angular solution independently and launching the app from Angular Custom Elements like this:

```
export class AppModule {
 constructor(private injector: Injector) {   }

 ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
     if (!customElements.get('app-root')) {
     const helloElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
     customElements.define('app-root', helloElement);
   }
 }
```

Source: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/howto-angular-elements-in-sharepoint-framework-projects-two-projects?utm_source=accom&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=Using%20Angular%20Elements%20in%20SharePoint%20Framework%20Projects%20Series

And my git repo: https://github.com/clementlepere/SPFX-AngularElements

It is still very WIP and I faced some encoding issue when running the build script (fixed using an encoding converter like notepad++ before running gulp serve)